# Are there UICollectionView delegate methods?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I am new to the iPhone and I am Working on the collection view at present. I have a doubt are there any delegate methods that will call when we scroll the collection view to top and bottom i.e.,scroll up and scroll down.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: UICollectionView is a subclass of UIScrollView, so you have access to any of the UIScrollViewDelegate methods. Check then out to see if any meet your needs.

Comment: `UICollectionView` is a `UIScrollView` subclass. All [`UIScrollViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html) methods can be implemented by the delegate instance. Also, there is a separate [`UICollectionViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use – `scrollViewDidScroll:`, – `scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:` and – `scrollViewDidScrollToTop:` methods in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Collection view is inherited from UIScrollView. You may implement methods from the same

you may refer them [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html)